# GSON / JSON converting from innerJsonObject

Tags: android, json, gson

I need to create the following JSON Object and than convert it to string using the GSON library (toJson(Object)). However, GSON appends the nameValuePair with each JSON Object, what do I need to do?

```
"Param_1": 
{
"SubParam_1": { type: String, required: true }
}
```

I'm putting these JSONObjects into a ParameterMap (android HTTP Client) and using GSON to convert the map to JSON String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the JSON "object" you've written is not even valid JSON!

If anything, you could create a JSON like this:

```
{
    "Param_1": {
        "SubParam_1": { "type": "String", "required": true }
    }
}
```

And that's very easy, you just need to have the correct class model, something like this:

```
public class YourClass {
  private Param Param_1;
}

public class Param {
  private SubParam SubParam_1;
}

public class SubParam {
  private String type;
  private boolean required;
}
```

And then you can use the method `.toJson()`, like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(yourObject);
```